# How to use conditionnal statement with startswith() on Python - dfply?

Tags: python, pandas, apply, dplyr, dfply

I'm doing data wrangling on Python, using the package dfply.

I want to create a new variable "a06", from 'FC06' of the dataset data_a, so that :

- a06 = 1 if FC06[i] starts with the character "1" (ex : FC06[i]=173)
- a06 = 2 if FC06[i] starts with the character "2"
- a06 = NaN if FC06[i] = NaN

For instance, with the input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'FC06':[173,170,220,float('nan'),110,230,float('nan')]})
```

I want to get the output :

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'a06':[1,1,2,float('nan'),1,2,float('nan')]})
```

On R it would be obtained by :

```
data_a %>% mutate(a06 = ifelse(substr(FC06,1,1)=="1",1,ifelse(substr(FC06,1,1)=="1",2,NaN)))
```

but I don't find how to do this with Python.

I achieved a first version with just 2 alternatives : NaN or 1, with :

```
data_a >>        mutate(a06=if_else((X['FC06'].apply(pd.isnull)),float('nan'),1)
```

but I can't find how to differentiate the result according to the first character of FC06.

(I tried things like :

```
(data_a >> mutate(a06=if_else(X['FC06'].apply(pd.isnull),float('nan'),if_else(X['FC06'].apply(str)[0]=='1',1,2))))
```

but without success : 
- [0] doesn't work there to get the first character
- and/or str() can't be used with apply (neither str.startswith('1'))

Does anybody knows how to solve such situations ?

Or another package to do that on Python ?

Thank you !!

Comment: Can you please provide some example data and your expected output? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) are some tips on how to make good, reproducible pandas examples.

Comment: Ok, for instance, my input can be :
    df = pd.DataFrame({'FC06':[173,170,220,float('nan'),110,230,float('nan')]})

Comment: and the expected output : df1= pd.DataFrame({'a06':[1,1,2,float('nan'),1,2,float('nan')]})

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51822709/edit) your question and provide these examples there.

Comment: Note, your examples provide *integers*, not strings... which are they?

Comment: Also, will they always start with 1, 2 or be NAN?

Comment: About the data type : there must be rather strings, since some values are like "110M" (the data are about functions in an association, 110M or 270 is the code of the function). if I write 
    type(data_a['FC06']), I get : pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: You want `data_a['FC06'].dtypes`. The series is of course of type series, you want the type of the *data* in the series. But it seems you have some object column, presumably from some csv?

Comment: They must always start with 1, 2 or NaN (if ever some start with something else, I want to associate them with '2')

Comment: Yes, indeed. it's logic that the type is series (I believed that it could be different like on R ;)). My dataset : data_a is a dataframe from a CSV, with several columns including FC06

Comment: Well, I've provided a solution that should work if your data is as messy as you think it might be, you could also try jpp's answer, in case your data is more well-behaved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have 3-digit numbers, you can use floor division:

```
df['FC06'] //= 100
```

If you have strings, you can use `pd.Series.mask`:

```
ints = pd.to_numeric(df['FC06'].astype(str).str[:1], errors='coerce')
df['FC06'].mask(df['FC06'].notnull(), ints, inplace=True)

print(df)

   FC06
0   1.0
1   1.0
2   2.0
3   NaN
4   1.0
5   2.0
6   NaN
```

You will notice that your integers become floats. This is forced by the existence of `NaN` values, which are considered `float`. In general, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you ! I would try to use dfply (or an equivalent of dplyr in R), but as long as it works it's very good :)